# Silence Django manage.py DeprecationWarning

Tags: django, cron, deprecated

Is there any way I can quieten deprecation warnings from manage.py?

We have some cron jobs which are throwing them up but no budget from the client to fix them, so I just want to quieten them for now until we can fix them properly.  I don't want to totally turn off cron email alerts though, as I'd like to know when something is properly broken.

I'm getting a couple of mails like this every day:

`DeprecationWarning: the sha module is deprecated; use the hashlib module instead`

(I need to upgrade django-registration it seems).

Thanks!

Ludo